# Placing orders in Magento without paying?

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, php-5.4

I was wondering whether it was possible to set the Magento backend up in a way that customers are able to place orders without paying for them?

So that orders are raised in the backend and I can then contact them regarding their order?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods which you could use for this purpose

1) Cash on delivery

2) Check or Money order

You can change the title of these method to whichever you like. Customer will not have to do payment for this.

To enable it

`Goto System >> Configuration >> Payment` Methods and enable either **"Check/Money Order"** or **"Cash On Delivery"**

Hope this helps